# NSDictionary is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I want to parse a local json and I was trying to do this like this but `testDict` is nil.  Can anyone help me please?

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    [self.searchResult removeAllObjects];
        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];
    NSString * firstLetter = [searchText substringWithRange:[searchText rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:0]];

    NSError *err = nil;
    NSString *aux=@"english_";
    NSString *updated = [aux stringByAppendingString:firstLetter];

    NSString *dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:updated ofType:@"json"];

    testDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath] options:kNilOptions error:&err];
```

Json is look something like this :

```
"Caaba": "(n.) The small and nearly cubical stone building, toward which all Mohammedans must pray.",
   "Caas": "(n. sing. &amp; pl.) Case.",
   "Cab": [
      "(n.) A kind of close carriage with two or four wheels, usually a public vehicle.",
      "(n.) The covered part of a locomotive, in which the engineer has his station.",
      "(n.) A Hebrew dry measure, containing a little over two (2.37) pints."
   ],
```

and I was checking to be a validate json

Comment: Can you post the JSON you try to parse please

Comment: And what does `err` tell you?

Comment: To me, this doesn't look like a valid json at all.

Comment: it not valid JSON: check your json first here http://pro.jsonlint.com/

Comment: Well, My guess is that the JSON returns you a dictionary but you are trying to using an `NSDictionary`.Try using an `NSArray` for the variable `testDict`

Comment: Valid JSON starts either with { or with [ . Yours starts with " . Therefore it is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code:

```
NSString *path = @"/Users/JohnApple/Desktop/myJsonFileForThisTest.json";
NSError *err;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path] options:kNilOptions error:&err];
NSLog(@"Here is the NSDicitonary if this worked --> %@",dict);
NSLog(@"Here is the NSError if it failed --> %@", err);
```

When I used the Json data you provided above:

```
"Caaba": "(n.) The small and nearly cubical stone building, toward which all Mohammedans must pray.",
"Caas": "(n. sing. &amp; pl.) Case.",
"Cab": [
  "(n.) A kind of close carriage with two or four wheels, usually a public vehicle.",
  "(n.) The covered part of a locomotive, in which the engineer has his station.",
  "(n.) A Hebrew dry measure, containing a little over two (2.37) pints."
],
```

I got this error:

`The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set`

It turns out your JSON was in bad format. To fix your Json, please add a `{` at the start of your json in the file and a `}` at the very end.
You can check to see if your JSON is in the correct format by checking [this site](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). Your NSDIctionary will be null if your data is invalid.

After putting your Json in the correct format, the following data was displayed correctly:

```
{
    Caaba = "(n.) The small and nearly cubical stone building, toward which all Mohammedans must pray.";
    Caas = "(n. sing. &amp; pl.) Case.";
    Cab =     (
        "(n.) A kind of close carriage with two or four wheels, usually a public vehicle.",
        "(n.) The covered part of a locomotive, in which the engineer has his station.",
        "(n.) A Hebrew dry measure, containing a little over two (2.37) pints."
    );
}
```